# MySQL Query is slow (Joins/counts)

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam

I have this query:

```
 SELECT `assemblies`.`id`,
   `assemblies`.`type`,
   `assemblies`.`champion`,
   `assemblies`.`name`,
   `assemblies`.`author`,
   `assemblies`.`githublastmod`,
   ( assemblies.forum IS NOT NULL ) AS forumExists,
   Count(votes.id)                  AS votesCount,
   Count(install_clicks.id)         AS installCount,
   Count(github_clicks.id)          AS githubCount,
   Count(forum_clicks.id)           AS forumCount
FROM   `assemblies`
   INNER JOIN `votes`
           ON `votes`.`assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`
   INNER JOIN `install_clicks`
           ON `install_clicks`.`assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`
   INNER JOIN `github_clicks`
           ON `github_clicks`.`assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`
   INNER JOIN `forum_clicks`
           ON `forum_clicks`.`assembly` = `assemblies`.`id`
WHERE  `assemblies`.`type` = 'utility'
   AND Unix_timestamp(Date(assemblies.githublastmod)) > '1419536536'
GROUP  BY `assemblies`.`id`
ORDER  BY `votescount` DESC,
      `githublastmod` DESC
```

For some reason this query is very slow, I'm using the database engine MyISAM. I hope someone can help me out here :)

Explain command:
[image]

Comment: Added the explain command as image (copy/paste failed for me :(), link to full image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/y8k8H.png

Comment: What indexes do you have in your tables? Are all fields involved in joining tables indexed?

Comment: I've only set the id as an index. Should I just add indexes for the other columns aswell?

Comment: You should add indexes on `votes`.`assembly`, `install_clicks`.`assembly, etc.

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, not `SHOW INDEXES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a case where making the subqueries for the counts will make it run a lot faster (and the values will be correct).

The problem with the original query is the explosion of the number of intermediate rows:  For each 'assembly', there were n1 votes, n2 installs, etc.  That led to n1*n2*... rows *per* assembly.

```
SELECT  `assemblies`.`id`, `assemblies`.`type`, `assemblies`.`champion`,
        `assemblies`.`name`, `assemblies`.`author`, `assemblies`.`githublastmod`,
        ( assemblies.forum IS NOT NULL ) AS forumExists, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  votes
            WHERE  `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id` 
      ) AS votesCount, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  install_clicks
            WHERE  `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id` 
      ) AS installCount, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  github_clicks
            WHERE  `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id` 
      ) AS githubCount, 
      ( SELECT  Count(*)
            FROM  forum_clicks.id
            WHERE  `assembly` = `assemblies`.`id` 
      ) AS forumCount
    FROM  `assemblies`
    WHERE  `assemblies`.`type` = 'utility'
      AND  Unix_timestamp(Date(assemblies.githublastmod)) > '1419536536'
    ORDER BY  `votescount` DESC, `githublastmod` DESC
```

Each secondary table needs an INDEX *starting* with `assembly`.

Comment: Are you sure this is faster? Could you please give us an `EXPLAIN` result with both options?

Comment: I'm not sure it is faster.  For one thing, I am _assuming_ that `assemblies` is a short table, and the others are long, with many rows per `assemblies.id`.  And I am assuming `assembly` is indexed.  I hope to see the `EXPLAIN`s.

Comment: Explain using this method (I believe this is working correctly): http://gyazo.com/e9fe505cab210fb1b54fe5d6cbbffaf1 --- Explain using my own query: http://gyazo.com/8bfebc979c57953a4ced5b5b7a3b1985

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be fixed using the right indices:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name_1 ON `votes`(`assembly`);
CREATE INDEX index_name_2 ON `install_clicks`(`assembly`);
CREATE INDEX index_name_3 ON `github_clicks`(`assembly`);
CREATE INDEX index_name_4 ON `forum_clicks`(`assembly`);
```

Try your query again after creating these indices and it should be quite faster.

Comment: As far as I can see this is working a lot better already. But it isn't picking a key at the forum_clicks. http://gyazo.com/8728fbac4c836192e386adb85170a6ae

Comment: Note that the `Rows` column is much smaller for each secondary table.  Note that the optimizer chose to start with forum_clicks instead of assemblies.

Comment: (side note: adding explains for both in a bit) --- Problem is almost fixed, The forum_clicks still contains all rows, is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: According to the shown `EXPLAIN`, the server knows that there's an index on `assembly`, but prefers not to use it. As @RickJames says, this may be because it is faster to scan all table than to use the index (depending on the column values distribution, for example). That said, you could try to add `forum_clicks.assembly` to the `Group By` clause.

Comment: The server is still to dumb to use it hahaha. I'm using Rick's answer as that is working perfectly, but couldn't have done it without you. I feel sorry I can only mark one post as anwer :(